# Get AD Computer's Description

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, active-directory

I need to get domain computer's description. From Registry I can only get local description, but I need Active Directory description. Any ideas?

Looking forward!
Thank you!

Comment: Use System.DirectoryServices to contact your AD and ask him :)

Comment: Can't find the right way to use it.. :( Don't you know?

Comment: Not in an AD environment ATM, so can't test anything. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813452/connect-to-active-directory-via-ldap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `DirectoryEntry` class (`System.DirectoryServices` namespace) to 
connect to Active Directory. Provide a username and password and the LDAP root path
to search for computer objects in Active Directory. Then use the `DirectorySearcher`
class to query for the computer object.

The code below shows how to search for a computer with the name *computer01*.
I've also added the *description* property to the properties to load 
(not all properties get loaded by default). In the code below you have to replace 
with the name of your domain controller. By the same token replace the  tags
with the name of your domain. For example if the name of your Active Directory server is
*server01* and your domain name is *fabrikam.com* then the LDAP path is `LDAP://server01/dc=fabrikam,dc=com`.

```
using (DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://<your-ad-server-name>/dc=<domain-name-part>,dc=<domain-name-part>",
     "Administrator", "Your Secure Password", AuthenticationTypes.Secure))
{
  using (DirectorySearcher adSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry))
  {
    string computerName = "computer01";
    adSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=computer)(cn=" + computerName + "))";
    adSearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
    adSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("description");
    SearchResult searchResult = adSearcher.FindOne();

    Console.Out.WriteLine(searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["description"].Value);
  }
}
```

Please note, that the code above searches the whole Active Directory for the computer object. 
To search only in the *Computers container* use the following LDAP path:

```
LDAP://<your-ad-server-name>/cn=Computers,dc=<domain-name-part>,dc=<domain-name-part>
```