# How to retrieve Specific user by LDAP Path in active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I have a problem, finding suitable interface to get the user from AD when I have it's LDAP path. I couldn't find anything on the internet, the community generally uses PrincipalSearcher but I'm wondering If you can use LDAP path as parameter.Does anyone have experience with that ?

Kindest Regards.

Comment: This looks like it might be what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813452/connect-to-active-directory-via-ldap

Comment: Don't have time to write an answer out, but I was in need of this same question answered just now. Couldn't find any answers that *actually* answered that question (the answer below is clearly filtering on SAMAccountName, which isn't the same thing). Anyway, the part I was missing: in LDAP, the path is known as the "distinguished name", and distinguishedName is an attribute, which you can then filter on the same way you can filter on any other attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DirectoryEntry for that:

```
public static bool GetAdUser(string userLoginID, out string userFirstName,
        out string userLastName, out string userEmailAddress)
{
    bool foundUser = false;
    userFirstName = null;
    userLastName = null;
    userEmailAddress = null;

    DirectoryEntry activeDirectory = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://MyDomainName.local", null, null, 
        AuthenticationTypes.ReadonlyServer);  // supply username and password parameters if needed

    try
    {
        DirectorySearcher adSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(activeDirectory);
        adSearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        adSearcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=user)(|(SAMAccountName={0})))", userLoginID);

        string[] adPropertyNames =
        {
            "sn",
            "givenname",
            "mail"
            // add more AD attributes to retrieve here as needed
        };

        foreach (string propertyName in adPropertyNames)
            adSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(propertyName);

        SearchResultCollection userSearchResult = adSearcher.FindAll();

        if (userSearchResult != null)
        {
            foreach (SearchResult adAccount in userSearchResult)
            {
                foundUser = true;
                ResultPropertyCollection accountProperties = adAccount.Properties;

                if (accountProperties != null)
                {
                    userFirstName = GetAdAccountPropertyValue(accountProperties, "givenname");
                    userLastName = GetAdAccountPropertyValue(accountProperties, "sn");
                    userEmailAddress = GetAdAccountPropertyValue(accountProperties, "mail");
                    // add more here as needed
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // log something
    }

    return foundUser;
}

private static string GetAdAccountPropertyValue(ResultPropertyCollection adAccountProperties, string propertyName)
{
    string result = null;

    ResultPropertyValueCollection adAccountPropertyValues = adAccountProperties[propertyName];

    if (adAccountPropertyValues != null)
    {
        result = String.Empty;  // property is valid at this point, so initialize its value to empty to show this

        if (adAccountPropertyValues.Count > 0)
        {
            object adAccountPropertyValue = adAccountPropertyValues[0];
            result = adAccountPropertyValue.ToString();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```