# The supplied credential is invalid when using LdapConnection

Tags: c#, ldap

I am attempting to connect to a LDAP server and do some searches.  I am using LdapConnection and NetworkCredential objects to do this.  Here is a sample of my code.  When I attempt to do the Bind, I get an error that states

> "The supplied credential is invalid."

I think my problem is I am not passing an expected value of Domain correctly.  This is my first time programming using these objects, and I have struggled to find an example that works for me.  Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

```
string myServerName = "111.22.333.444:389";

string myUserName = "MyLogin,ou=Systems,ou=LOCATION,o=Internal,dc=MYCOMPANY,dc=COM";

string myPassword = "MyPassword";

string myDomain = "ou=Systems,ou=LOCATION,o=Internal,dc=MYCOMPANY,dc=COM";

LdapConnection myConnection = new LdapConnection(myServerName);

NetworkCredetial myCredential = new NetworkCredential(myUserName, myPassword, myDomain);

myConnection.Bind(myCredential);
```

Comment: There are several values here that are incorrect.  Please check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813452/connect-to-active-directory-via-ldap

Answer (score 0):

The post is from 2017 but I have solution for your problem.
Use `MYCOMPANY\MyLogin` instead LDAP path, and provide `LdapConnection` by `LdapDirectoryIdentifier` and `NetworkCredential`.

```cs
var myServerName = "111.22.333.444";
var ldapPort = 389;

var myLogin = "MYCOMPANY\\MyLogin";
var myPassword = "MyPassword";

var connection = new LdapConnection(
        new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(ldapServer, ldapPort),
        new System.Net.NetworkCredential(myLogin, password), AuthType.Basic);

connection.SessionOptions.ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOptions.None;
connection.Bind();
```

Works fine for me.