# With VB.Net and .Net 2.0, How to query AD to check if user exists or not?

Tags: .net, vb.net, active-directory

I have found this code but it is for .Net 3.5+

```
' set up domain context    
Dim ctx As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)

' find a user
Dim user As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName")

If user IsNot Nothing Then
   ' user exists - do something here....               
Else
   ' user does not exist - do something else....
End If
```

Is there any alternative that could work in .Net 2.0?

Comment: Look at some of the examples using DirectoryEntry object, like in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813452/connect-to-active-directory-via-ldap